# Showing project structure and contents on a web page, like Eclipse's package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, jquery-ui, web-applications, ria

I have my project on Eclipse. There I use the Package Explorer to see its structure and the contents of each file. I would like to publish that in the web so others can see the project. Is there some kind of UI component that would allow me to do that?

Comment: The JavaDocs tool gives a pretty good 'web friendly' representation of an API.

Comment: @Andrew: I am looking to show code, not api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the use of a shared code repository, like [github](https://github.com/). It allows you to make versioning and reach, of course, the requeriment you are looking for: Web publishing. And if you want others can work on your project, this kind of tools are the best option.

Comment: I was looking for something like package explorer on the left and code showing on the right, pretty much like eclipse.